# Ошибка локализации JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Начал создавать приложение на javafx и столкнулся с ошибкой. Как её исправить?

Вот класс Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {
/*  Start program!!!  */

FXMLLoader fXMLLoader_MainMenu;

@Override
public void start(Stage stageMainMenu) throws Exception {
    StorageVariables storageVariables=new StorageVariables();

    fXMLLoader_MainMenu=new FXMLLoader();
    fXMLLoader_MainMenu.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
    fXMLLoader_MainMenu.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample.Properties.MainMenu", new Locale("ru")));

    Parent panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
    Scene scene=new Scene(panel,700,500);
    stageMainMenu.setScene(scene);
    stageMainMenu.setTitle(fXMLLoader_MainMenu.getResources().getString("key_MainMenu_Title")); //titleMainMenu
    stageMainMenu.show();

    System.out.println("   Program start!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Вот файл fxml:

```
    <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="sample.ControllerProgramGuide">
     <children>
       <ImageView fitHeight="500.0" fitWidth="700.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@res/ФонГлавногоОкна.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fitHeight="45.0" fitWidth="29.0" layoutX="647.0" layoutY="18.0" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@res/ЗнакВопроса.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fx:id="imgBtnQuestion" blendMode="HARD_LIGHT" fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="635.0" layoutY="16.0" opacity="0.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@res/ДляКнопки5050.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <Button fx:id="btnQuestion" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="635.0" layoutY="15.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseEntered="#mouseEnteredBtnQUESTION" onMouseExited="#mouseExitedBtnQUESTION" onMousePressed="#inquiryQuestionBtnQUESTION" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
   <Label layoutX="215.0" layoutY="65.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="275.0" text="%key_MainMenu_Title" textFill="#070606" >
     <font>
        <Font size="25.0" />
     </font>
   </Label>
 </children>
</Pane>
```

Ошибка:

> No resources specified.
>   /D:/workspace/Assist/out/production/Assist/sample/MainMenu.fxml:29
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:308)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:200)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:591)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2472)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2177)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)   at
>   sample.Main.start(Main.java:24)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception in Application start method Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified.   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:308)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:200)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:591)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2472)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2177)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)   at
>   sample.Main.start(Main.java:24)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
>   ... 1 more

Ошибка появляется лишь при добавлении label текст ключа из файла property.

```
 text="%key_MainMenu_Title"
```

Название ключа я написал правильно.

Comment: а контроллер ControllerProgramGuide почему не кинул?

Comment: В нем ничего ещё нет

Answer (score 1):

Я всё понял, добавил инициализацию в контроллере и всё заработало)